# Redirect to a specific webpage after users select from dropdown menu using a form and php

Tags: php, forms, redirect, menu

I am developing a webpage for a friend, he rents cars,
so I want dropdown menus and a submit button where the user can choose the kind of car they are looking for.

example:

```
type of car:
- Small
- Medium
- Large

Price Range:
- $100
- $200
- $300
```

and depending on the conditions redirect them to a specific page.
I am pretty sure I can archive this using a form in html like the one I currently have

```
<form action="php/cars.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frmdata">
<table width="100%">

  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <select id="type" name="type">
        <option value="1" data-description="Small Car">Small Car/option>
        <option value="2" data-description="Medium Car">Medium Car</option>
        <option value="3" data-description="Large Car">Large Car</option>
    </select>

    <select name="price" id="price">
      <option value="a">100</option>
      <option value="b">200</option>
      <option value="c">300</option>

    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="bottom"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
```

Now, the problem comes in my php,

What am I doing wrong? It does load the php, so the problem is not in the html.
Also, if there´s a better way to do achieve this I am ready for it :)

```
<?php

switch ($_POST['type'].$_POST['price']) {
    case "1a":
        $redirectLocation = "http://google.com";
    case "2a":
        $redirectLocation = "http://apple.com";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never actually do the redirect:

```
<?php
switch ($_POST['type'].$_POST['price']) {
    case "1a":
        $redirectLocation = "http://google.com";
        break;
    case "2a":
        $redirectLocation = "http://apple.com";
        break;
}
header('Location: ' . $redirectLocation);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: You'll want to add break statements to your cases, otherwise I think $redirectLocation is going to be apple.com even for case 1a

Answer (score 0):

try if else condition first accept input from user pass it to PAGE AND  then check condition if and else . and then redirect him